# JSF 2.2 webapp works on Local Machine but not on the Server

Tags: jsf, amazon-ec2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to create a web application using jsf 2.2. My application is using **JERSEY Restful, jre 1.8, JSF 2.2, Primefaces.**

It works perfectly fine on my local machine but on AWS(EC2- Tomcat by bitnami-free tier) I get the error(Error log at the bottom.)

***Thank you so much for your help in Advance.***

I'm using the following libraries

[image]

Here's my Web.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MYAPP</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**Error Log**
26-Apr-2018 03:33:43.130 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:27)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:48)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

26-Apr-2018 03:33:43.463 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:27)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:48)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

26-Apr-2018 03:39:45.299 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-24] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:27)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:48)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

26-Apr-2018 03:39:45.716 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-24] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:27)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:48)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

26-Apr-2018 04:57:18.310 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-25] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
    at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:27)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:48)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

Comment: please improve your title

Comment: Since you are using EC2, why don't you use a real application server like Wildfly, Glassfish or Wildfly-swarm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to include different versions of JSF in your project which causes the problem. I can see javax.faces-2.3.2 in your dependencies as well as jsf-api-2.2.9/jsf-impl-2.2.9. The method addSearchKeywordResolver in 
javax.faces.application.Application is called and can't be found (as the stack trace tells you). This method is only 
part of JSF 2.3. However the JSF 2.2 class seems to be used. The method is called by PrimeFaces because PrimeFaces thinks you are using JSF 2.3 because the class javax.faces.component.UIImportConstants can be found in the class path (in javax.faces-2.3.2 dependency). I think the solution is only to include depedencies of one JSF version.

Comment: Alex, thank you so much. Also the web service that I set up in my app doesn't work on AWS. Any clue of why this might happen?

Answer (score -1):

you can add `<scope>provided</scope>` in your pom.xml at the bottom of `<version>6.2</version>`. And final code like in below:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```